Verification of Apache POI using gpg failed with 'not a trusted signature'
I'm trying to verify the Apache POI download using GPG simple installer download
(gnupg-w32-2.4.7_20241125.exe for windows from www.gnupg.org)
I've downloaded

apache-poi-src-5.3.0-20240625.zip
apache-poi-src-5.3.0-20240625.zip.asc and
keys.asc

On running the verification command I get the following warning:

Signature made on 06/25/24 07:10:08 Eastern
using RSA key ......
Good signature from "PJ Fanning (..apache.org/) fanningpj@apache.org" [unknown]
aka "PJ Fanning (GitHub noreply address) ....
aka "PJ Fanning <fanningpj@yahoo,com>" [unknown]
WARNING : This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint : 6BA4 DA8B 1C88 A494 28A2 9C3D 0C69 C1EF 4118 1E13

Can you advise how I should proceed?
I was following the instructions I'd searched to verify the Apache POI download. I was expecting the verification to succeed.

The apache-poi-src-5.3.0-20240625.zip  SHA-512 checksum matches.

Did you tell GPG that you trust signatures from the Apache POI team?

Thank you for the response. Re. the comment about telling GPG to trust the signatures.. i thought that was the point of the process.. you need to get confirmation from within the circle of trust that its valid and was generated by the person claiming to have generated it.
